# Is there anyway to create a Spring Aspect advice that triggers on any method that is NOT annotated by certain annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-annotations, spring-aspects

Basically I am trying to create a log system that will log most of the controller methods (their parameters, bodies, status codes and so on), however, there are few controller methods I do not want to log for some specific reasons. I do not want to create an annotation that indicates this method will be logged (because there are gonna be plenty), instead, I want to create an annotation that indicates this method should NOT be logged. Obviously, I cannot negate an annotation in a Spring Aspect advice, so is there any workaround for it? (such as getting a method's all annotations from `ProceedingJoinPoint`, then check if they contain that `NoLog` annotation)

Comment: Hi kgh05y. If your question has been solved, please mark an answer. That is the way to mark a question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
Method method = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass()
      .getMethod(methodSignature.getMethod().getName(),
                 methodSignature.getMethod().getParameterTypes());
CustomAnnotation annotation = method.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
```

Well, looks like you can use the above codes to attempt to get the `CustomAnnotation` on your methods, if your methods are NOT annotated by this `CustomAnnotation`, a `null` will be returned, otherwise a `Proxy` object will be returned